# Find and replace/update specific entries from all rows of selected columns in DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, replace, datatable

In a DataTable, I am trying to find specific string entries in order to replace them or update them.

However, it has to be done only for specific columns (data type is string).

What I need is to select all these columns using their names or caption, then find and replace/update all strings of these columns with specific condition.

E.g. Select columns using their names (names are in a `List<string>` or `string[]`), then search for each and every string which contains `%` at the beginning of the string and replace it with `@`.

A similar try with SQL would be `select col,replace(col,'%','@') from dtTable where col like '@%'`

I was trying to do this in a single `LINQ` query, but no success so far. Any examples of `LINQ` would be a great help.

Comment: can you add a code sample so it could be easier to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ should be used only to query collections not to modify them. Use simple loops and [`DataRow.Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.field%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) + [`DataRow.SetField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.setfield%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) which are strongly typed and support nullables:

```
List<string> colsToUpdate = new List<string> { "Column1", "Column2", "..." };
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    foreach (String colName in colsToUpdate)
    {
        string oldValue = row.Field<string>(colName);
        if(oldValue.StartsWith("%"))
            row.SetField(colName, "@" + oldValue.Substring(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, I agree.
I was already doing this right at the time of inserting these strings into DataTable. However, this is a bit slower to go through this process for each and every entry (there is a huge data to load). That's why I was looking for something that could do this in a one shot, like we do it with an SQL query for a single column.

`select col,replace(col,'%','@') from dtTable where col like '@%'`

Comment: @ChP: this is the most efficient approach to update an already filled `DataTable`. Of course it's always more efficient to avoid invalid data in the first place, for example by using a different sql (if the data came from a database). I suspect that you trying to optimize at the the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks, that's correct. I could try to do this with each column separately (if it's possible to replace all entries in one shot). Or, the process you have mentioned works well or I could continue with what I am doing while loading the data itself. Actually, this data is coming from API, over which I have no control.

Comment: @ChP: you can trust me as i'm a big fan of LINQ. Every LINQ approach would be less efficient, less readable and less maintainable in this case. A linq query should not have side-effects at all and a `DataTable` modification that you're enumerating at the same time is one. So you would have to create a blank new `DataTable` to solve this with LINQ. But even than you have to intialize `DataRows` which is difficult with LINQ. Finally, LINQ uses also loops under the hood.

Comment: wow, I guess it is more clear now, the approach that we are using is the correct one, it's also better to validate the data that is being loaded, like null or empty or whitespace, etc.
If we really force LINQ on it, that would actually downgrade the performance in this case because that would be a workaround solution.
Thanks a lot.